MatRadioGroupComp warning in console
I have this piece of HTML in my project of angular:
<th2-mat-radio-group
    [radioButtonList]="isOneWayRadioButtons"
    [form]="typeSettingForm"
    formControlFieldName="isOneWay"
    [required]="false"
    name="isOneWay">
</th2-mat-radio-group>

but I keep getting this warning in the console even though I'm not using the disabled attribute here. If I delete the [form] part the warning disappears but the form stops working.

Th2MatRadioGroupComponent.ngfactory.js:212
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
Example:

      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });

I have this in my settings-form.ts:
isOneWay: new FormControl({ value: false, disabled: true }, []),


How can I delete this warning and keep the buttons functional? Thank you so much.
I want to delete de warning from the console but keep having the form working correct.

please share the code of th2-mat-radio-group

Its a private component and I don't have access to it but its not a matter of th2-mat-radio-group because I had the same issue in other part of the code and I solved it. But for some reason I can't do it here.

In the HTML of th2-mat-radio-group remove the [disabled] attribute you have added. Instead set the disabled flag programmatically.
const formCtrl = this.form.get('someCtrl');

if(this.someCondition) {
    formCtrl.enable();
} else {
    formCtrl.disable();
}


You can also do the same using the below directive, which removes disabled but does the same thing.
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Directive({
  selector: '([formControlName], [formControl])[disabledControl]',
})
export class DisabledControlDirective {
  @Input() set disabledControl(state: boolean) {
    const action = state ? 'disable' : 'enable'
    this.ngControl.control[action]()
  }

  constructor(private readonly ngControl: NgControl) {}
}

HTML:
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" [disabledControl]="disabledName" />
</form>

Article - Disable a reactive form control using custom directive

I'm not using any disabled attribute:
<th2-mat-radio-group
[radioButtonList]="isOneWayRadioButtons"
[form]="typeSettingForm"
formControlFieldName="isOneWay"
[required]="false"
name="isOneWay">


@JenniferYasmin maybe you are using inside the component th2-mat-radio-group, check your codebase, if any [disabled] in html is used for reactive forms

@JenniferYasmin Please inform the package author that this warning needs to be fixed, since you do not have control, the problem does not seem to be from your code, looking at what is shared by you

As I said, sorry if I'm not explaining well, I had the same issue some weeks ago and it worked out changing the [form] to         [formControl]="typeSettingForm.get('something')" but here it doesn't work

They said it's a frontend error: I solved it in another case by chaning the form [form] to [formControl]="typeSettingForm.get('something')" but in this case it stops working.

@JenniferYasmin warning is point to Th2MatRadioGroupComponent.ngfactory.js:212 so the inner component to be fixed, also its a warning not an error
